# In Se-Builder evals, how can you reference stored variables?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using se-Builder (not selenium ide) http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder/

and I am trying to use an assertEval and reference a previously stored variable in the javascript line.

In the selenium IDE, you reference it using a storedVars object, however the following doesn't seem to work. (I get a script error). I have also tried returning just hw and ${hw} but nothing seems to work. Here is the documentation, which doesn't seem to mention this. https://github.com/sebuilder/se-builder/wiki

```
store
"HelloWorld"
hw

assertEval
return storedVars['hw'] // this is the problem line
"HelloWorld"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

The eval command does insert variables into eval with this:

```
${var}
```

notation.

What was screwing me up is that it inserts everything as is. So if you have a string stored as myText with the value: "some text" and try to insert it into your javascript.

```
var myText = ${myText};
```

It does not insert as

```
var myText = "some text";
```

as I incorrectly assumed (this is pretty obvious looking back that it was a terrible assumption). It is inserted directly:

```
var myText = some text;
```

what you need to do is

```
var myText = "${myText}";
```

so the result ends up like this:

```
var myText = "some text";
```

which was giving me lots of errors, but nothing helpful. I know this answer seems obvious, but I am posting the answer in case someone is making the same mistake I was.

Another thing to be aware of is the new lines will automatically be inserted into the js, which while cause another error. Which was also happening to me. I ended up needing to store an eval which removed all new lines from the element I was looking for and then storing that text.